# Criação de Busca com Filtros

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Olá, no meu projeto preciso filtrar os resultados com os seguintes parâmetros: Salário Mínimo e Salário Máximo, Tipo de Contrato. Porém só funciona caso o usuário escolher as opções, caso ele escolha filtrar apenas por tipo de contrato e deixar o Salário em branco, a busca não funciona.

O site do Mercado Livre tem a busca do jeito que eu quero fazer, quando se filtra o resultado, na url vai adicionando os filtros conforme o usuário vai escolhendo.

Futuramente desejo adicionar outros filtros e ordenação dos resultados.

**Página Principal:**

```
<form class="filter" action="/search" method="POST">
    <h2>Filtrar Por</h2>

    <div class="salario">
        <h3>Salário</h3>
        <select class="salario_min" name="salario_min">
            <option value="">Mínimo</option>
            <option value="400">400</option>
            <option value="500">500</option>
            <option value="600">600</option>
            <option value="700">700</option>
            <option value="800">800</option>
            <option value="900">900</option>
            <option value="1000">1000</option>
            <option value="1200">1200</option>
            <option value="1400">1400</option>
            <option value="1600">1600</option>
            <option value="1800">1800</option>
            <option value="2000">2000</option>
        </select>

        <select class="salario_max" name="salario_max">
            <option value="">Máximo</option>
            <option value="400">400</option>
            <option value="500">500</option>
            <option value="600">600</option>
            <option value="700">700</option>
            <option value="800">800</option>
            <option value="900">900</option>
            <option value="1000">1000</option>
            <option value="1200">1200</option>
            <option value="1400">1400</option>
            <option value="1600">1600</option>
            <option value="1800">1800</option>
            <option value="2000">2000</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="tipo">
        <h3>Tipo de Contrato</h3>

        <select class="tipo" name="tipo">
            <option value="">Todos</option>
            <option value="1">Integral</option>
            <option value="2">Temporário</option>
            <option value="3">Estágio</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" name="filtrar" class="btn">Aplicar Filtros</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Para fazer tal coisa terás de utilizar Javascript para mudar o URL à medida que escolhes uma opção, mas isso é apenas visual, o que tem de acontecer na realidade é quando uma opção é escolhida tens que fazer um request http tipo post ou get com os parametros escolhidos para o link/api que te devolve os resultados de acordo com o que foi submetido.

Comment: Cadê o código PHP?

Comment: Terá que usar AJAX! dê uma pesquisada na web e depois edite a pergunta.